# PHP replace between pre tags

Tags: php, replace

I want replace the `<br />` tag between the `<pre></pre>` tags in PHP.
Like this:

```
$content = "Hello,<br /> <-- don't replace

Line 1<br /> <-- don't replace
Line 2<br /> <-- don't replace

<pre>Line 3<br /> <-- replace
Line 4</pre>";
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Try [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: didnt find any pre tag in $content or you want to replace br tag between <code></code> tags

Comment: @Simon911 replace <br /> with what ?

Comment: @Bigood: Trying [to bring about the end of times](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)?

Comment: Oops, I am sorry, I mean <pre></pre> tags in $content

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist With nothing, the <pre></pre> tags shows a code, but I had a nl2br(); function, so the <pre></pre> tags shows too the <br /> tags.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You mean [this end of times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1437016)? :)

Comment: @Bigood: Yup, the blogpost I linked to talks about that answer, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_string($string, $start, $end){
 $string = " ".$string;
 $pos = strpos($string,$start);
 if ($pos == 0) return "";
     $pos += strlen($start);

 $len = strpos($string,$end,$pos) - $pos;

 $changeString = str_replace("<br />", "<replacement>", substr($string,$pos,$len) ); 
 // above line replace <br /> data with <replacement>

 return substr($string,0,$pos).$changeString.substr($string,$pos+$len);
}


$parsed = get_string($content , "<pre>", "</pre>");
echo $parsed;
```

> I m confused as there is no **pre** tag in $content in your post ...
>   only i see is **code** tag

Comment: @Simon911 Try some hit and run yourself!... it will produced the required result!